# Multiple Column LookUp Control

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to use look up control for select any value of basic information on my application,
also my look up control must be contain filtering.
so as bellow image :
[image]

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a grid in a partial view and call them by using dialog in jquery.